# Android app's "open in browser" link redirects to... the Android app!

Tags: support, android-app

I have a Samsung 7 Android phone.  My Stack Exchange app redirects me to the Stack Exchange app whenever I try to "open in browser".

Comment: Are you talking about SE app or SO app too? Did you try different sites? Also, if you post bug report from your device app will automatically add device/app specific info to the post body, so you don't need to say about model by self.

Comment: There are different stack exchange apps!?

Comment: [yep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299328/339911). One for SO only, and another for any SE site.

Comment: How the app is called?

Answer (score 1):

You're caught in logic circle.

The Stack Exchange app is probably using the "web browser" intent, which would normally just open a web browser on your phone.

However, Chrome has a feature where it can identify links that are associated with particular apps. For instance, if you're on a web page and you click a link to a Twitter post, it will open the Twitter app (if you have it) instead.

You should be able to turn that off by going to the settings for the Stack Exchange app, choosing "open by default", and changing the option under "Open supported links". You can also modify the URLs for which this will work.

This will probably vary by your version of Android and possibly whatever modifications the OEM has created. (Samsung is notorious for moving things around.) I was able to do this with vanilla Android 7.1.2 on a Pixel.

Comment: Samsung devices (maybe even Android in general) has a "Default apps" configuration in the OS settings. I recently ran into this same problem on a Galaxy S7. I opened an SO url and was prompted which app to use to open it, and chose the SO app. Since then, from within the app, trying to "open in browser" would just open the app again. I had to reset the default app for SO urls back to the web browser in the OS settings